# Horizontal scroll bar for a div

Tags: html, css, blueprint-css

Hai,

I have a div with fixed height and width, lets say i have width:400px; and height:200px; for a div.

How to bring the horizontal scroll bar for this div

Answer (score 2):

By giving it the

```
overflow: auto
```

CSS property and filling it with content that is wider, but not taller, than the DIV itself.

Answer (score 2):

type

```
div {
overflow-x:auto; /* Horizontal scroll  */ 
overflow-y:auto; /* Vertical scroll   */
}
```

or use

```
div {
overflow:auto; /* For Both */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use This ***CSS***

```
  <div class="DataGridXScroll">

  </div>

.DataGridXScroll
{
    width: 1000px;     
    height: 300px; 
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```